# ACF (Wordpress) the_field doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

My code:

```
 <p><?php the_field('myimage'); ?></p>
```

token from: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/code-examples/

It displays nothing. Why?

Answer (score 0):

If it's an image you need the `<img>` tag:

```
<img src="<?php the_field('myimage'); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the custom field value using the get_field. It returns array of value. To get the image url use the following code.

```
   <?php $image = get_field('myimage'); ?>

   <img src="<?php $image['url']; ?>" />
```

Comment: Could you provide an explenation with your code? It might help OP or future users more.